# React Native Expo: Access to Secure Store key retrieves null but refreshing the page brings data

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm working on a POC building a React Native with expo application (I have no experience developing apps but I gave it a try). I'm trying after login (AuthProvider) and getting redirected to the main page to access a key in my secure store:

```
useEffect(() => {
    SecureStore.getItemAsync("environments").then((env) =>{
        console.log('Secure Store Env: '+env);
        getApplications(env);//this makes a http request to a serivice
    });               
},[]);
```

When happens the first time I see:  *LOG  Secure Store Env: null*, but after refresh (Command + r) seems it gets a value.

In this case what is the best practice retrieving the values to make a second HTTP request and ensure I retrieve the values from my Secure Store?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach instead. This ensures that the request is made only when the value from Secure Store exists.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchKey= async () => {
    const env = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("environments");
    console.log('Secure Store Env: ' + env);
    if (env) getApplications(env);
  };

  fetchKey();
}, []);
```